# Differences between unicorn stdout log production log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, unicorn

I've built a rails applications that stores images in a hierarchy like structure. Something like: `Surveyor > Survey > SurveySeason > ... > Capture > Image`

A `Capture` can be sorted at a variety of levels in the hierarchy.

Today, one of my users reported that while working at one of these hierarchy levels, an "error" occurred (500) and then she noticed data was missing: All the data for a specific `SurveySeason` (it's children as well) was deleted, both from the database and from the filesystem.

My initial guess was that she accidentally hit the delete button for the `SurveySeason`, while thinking she was deleting a single `Capture` (a task she was doing around that time). A UI bug, if you will.

To confirm this, I've dug into the log files, which has led me to a few other questions.

unicorn.stdout.log

```
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:28] "GET /captures/7990?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.9869
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:30] "DELETE /captures/7990 HTTP/1.0" 302 - 1.3208
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:30] "GET /survey_seasons/46 HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2305
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:32] "GET /application/treedata HTTP/1.0" 200 - 1.9542
<ip-address-No2> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:35] "GET /historic_captures/15345?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.6459
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:37] "GET /captures/7996?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 200 - 1.0446
<ip-address-No2> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:40] "POST /historic_captures/move HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0733
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:45] "GET /captures/7984?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 200 - 1.0281
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:50] "GET /captures/7984?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 1.0118
----><ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:58] "DELETE /500 HTTP/1.0" 500 643 7.9431
<ip-address-No2> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:42:59] "GET /historic_captures/15634?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.5702
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:01] "GET /404 HTTP/1.0" 404 728 0.0110
<ip-address-No2> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:03] "POST /historic_captures/move HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0620
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:11] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 - 2.9165
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:11] "GET /application/treedata HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0133
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:18] "GET /application/treedata?id=11&type=Surveyor HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.0071
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:20] "GET /application/treedata?id=40&type=Survey HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0111
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:22] "GET /surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2521
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:27] "GET /surveys/23?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.3092
<ip-address-No2> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:28] "GET /historic_captures/15634?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.6675
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:28] "GET /application/treedata?id=23&type=Survey HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.0126
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:30] "GET /surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2498
<ip-address-No2> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:32] "GET /historic_captures/15344?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 200 - 0.6263
<ip-address-No2> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:35] "GET /historic_captures/15634?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.5708
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:38] "GET /surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.3119
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:39] "GET /surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2575
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:47] "GET /surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2543
--------><ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:51] "DELETE /survey_seasons/46 HTTP/1.0" 302 - 193.3085
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:52] "GET /surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.3568
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:54] "GET /surveys/23?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2928
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:43:56] "GET /surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.3733
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:44:13] "GET /surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2504
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:44:25] "GET /surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.4014
<ip-address-No1> - - [17/Jun/2014 15:44:29] "GET /surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D HTTP/1.0" 304 - 0.2655
```

production.log

```
Started DELETE "/captures/7990" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:42:28 -0700
Processing by CapturesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"IonwCsBlvoFTY/GrY3srK5wtUZDi3UqEbLIXwi+spaU=", "id"=>"7990"}
Redirected to http://envi-mountain-0003.envi.uvic.ca/survey_seasons/46
Completed 302 Found in 1318.1ms (ActiveRecord: 18.8ms)
Started GET "/survey_seasons/46" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:42:30 -0700
Processing by SurveySeasonsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"46"}
            Completed 200 OK in 227.6ms (Views: 219.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
Started GET "/application/treedata" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:42:30 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#treedata as JSON
  Completed 200 OK in 1950.9ms (Views: 902.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1048.0ms)
Started GET "/historic_captures/15345?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No2> at 2014-06-17 15:42:34 -0700
Processing by HistoricCapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"15345"}
                Completed 200 OK in 619.9ms (Views: 293.4ms | ActiveRecord: 100.1ms)
Started GET "/captures/7996?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:42:36 -0700
Processing by CapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"7996"}
                  Completed 200 OK in 1018.6ms (Views: 254.3ms | ActiveRecord: 227.5ms)
Started POST "/historic_captures/move" for <ip-address-No2> at 2014-06-17 15:42:40 -0700
Processing by HistoricCapturesController#move as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15345", "parent_id"=>"1772", "parent_type"=>"HistoricVisit"}
Completed 200 OK in 70.5ms (ActiveRecord: 11.9ms)
Started GET "/captures/7984?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:42:44 -0700
Processing by CapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"7984"}
                  Completed 200 OK in 1003.3ms (Views: 242.6ms | ActiveRecord: 209.6ms)
Started GET "/captures/7984?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:42:49 -0700
Processing by CapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"7984"}
                  Completed 200 OK in 986.3ms (Views: 240.3ms | ActiveRecord: 205.5ms)
---->Started DELETE "/captures/7984" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:42:50 -0700
Processing by CapturesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"IonwCsBlvoFTY/GrY3srK5wtUZDi3UqEbLIXwi+spaU=", "id"=>"7984"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7914.9ms

Sent mail to me@gmail.com (8.7ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `filesystem_path' for nil:NilClass):
  app/decorators/controllers/captures_controller_decorator.rb:52:in `destroy'


Started GET "/historic_captures/15634?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No2> at 2014-06-17 15:42:58 -0700
Processing by HistoricCapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"15634"}
                Completed 200 OK in 545.5ms (Views: 239.0ms | ActiveRecord: 98.9ms)
Started GET "/captures/7984" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:01 -0700
Processing by CapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7984"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 6.0ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Capture with id=7984):
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:344:in `find_one'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:315:in `find_with_ids'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:107:in `find'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find'
  cancan (1.6.9) lib/cancan/model_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:20:in `find'
  cancan (1.6.9) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:114:in `find_resource'
  cancan (1.6.9) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:68:in `load_resource_instance'
  cancan (1.6.9) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:32:in `load_resource'
  cancan (1.6.9) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:25:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
  cancan (1.6.9) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:10:in `block in add_before_filter'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:440:in `_run__521194440980891993__process_action__1920079375602021026__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
  exception_notification (4.0.1) lib/exception_notification/rack.rb:28:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack-pjax (0.7.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.17) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1749978080951018086__call__3020754741183455638__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.17) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.17) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
  railties (3.2.17) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/commonlogger.rb:33:in `call'
  sinatra (1.3.5) lib/sinatra/base.rb:161:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/chunked.rb:43:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:572:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:666:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:521:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:532:in `maintain_worker_count'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:290:in `join'
  unicorn (4.8.2) bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
  /rails_applications/deployments/meat/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /rails_applications/deployments/meat/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
Started POST "/historic_captures/move" for <ip-address-No2> at 2014-06-17 15:43:03 -0700
Processing by HistoricCapturesController#move as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"15345", "parent_id"=>"10", "parent_type"=>"SurveySeason"}
Completed 200 OK in 59.2ms (ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
Started GET "/" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:08 -0700
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"layout"=>"app/views/layouts/application.html.erb"}
                  Completed 200 OK in 2912.3ms (Views: 467.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2444.4ms)
Started GET "/application/treedata" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:11 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#treedata as JSON
  Completed 200 OK in 10.6ms (Views: 9.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
Started GET "/application/treedata?id=11&type=Surveyor" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:18 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#treedata as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"11", "type"=>"Surveyor"}
  Completed 200 OK in 4.2ms (Views: 2.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
Started GET "/application/treedata?id=40&type=Survey" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:20 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#treedata as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"40", "type"=>"Survey"}
  Completed 200 OK in 8.2ms (Views: 3.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
Started GET "/surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:21 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"40"}
            Completed 200 OK in 227.6ms (Views: 219.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
Started GET "/surveys/23?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:27 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"23"}
            Completed 200 OK in 284.3ms (Views: 276.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
Started GET "/historic_captures/15634?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No2> at 2014-06-17 15:43:27 -0700
Processing by HistoricCapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"15634"}
                Completed 200 OK in 641.7ms (Views: 234.2ms | ActiveRecord: 125.7ms)
Started GET "/application/treedata?id=23&type=Survey" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:28 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#treedata as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"23", "type"=>"Survey"}
  Completed 200 OK in 10.0ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
Started GET "/surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:29 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"40"}
            Completed 200 OK in 225.0ms (Views: 217.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
Started GET "/historic_captures/15344?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No2> at 2014-06-17 15:43:31 -0700
Processing by HistoricCapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"15344"}
                Completed 200 OK in 601.2ms (Views: 234.7ms | ActiveRecord: 100.2ms)
Started GET "/historic_captures/15634?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No2> at 2014-06-17 15:43:35 -0700
Processing by HistoricCapturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"15634"}
                Completed 200 OK in 545.2ms (Views: 229.1ms | ActiveRecord: 99.9ms)
Started GET "/surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:37 -0700
Processing by SurveyorsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"11"}
            Completed 200 OK in 286.2ms (Views: 278.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
Started GET "/surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:39 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"40"}
            Completed 200 OK in 232.7ms (Views: 225.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
Started GET "/surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:47 -0700
Processing by SurveyorsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"11"}
            Completed 200 OK in 228.9ms (Views: 221.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
Redirected to http://envi-mountain-0003.envi.uvic.ca/surveys/40
-------->Completed 302 Found in 193305.5ms (ActiveRecord: 11008.7ms)
Started GET "/surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:52 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"40"}
            Completed 200 OK in 328.6ms (Views: 320.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
Started GET "/surveys/23?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:54 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"23"}
            Completed 200 OK in 268.4ms (Views: 261.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
Started GET "/surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:43:56 -0700
Processing by SurveyorsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"11"}
            Completed 200 OK in 347.9ms (Views: 339.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
Started GET "/surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:44:13 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"40"}
            Completed 200 OK in 226.3ms (Views: 218.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
Started GET "/surveyors/11?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:44:25 -0700
Processing by SurveyorsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"11"}
            Completed 200 OK in 376.3ms (Views: 367.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
Started GET "/surveys/40?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for <ip-address-No1> at 2014-06-17 15:44:29 -0700
Processing by SurveysController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "id"=>"40"}
            Completed 200 OK in 240.8ms (Views: 232.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Note: I've replaced valid ip addressed with .

In both logs, I've prefixed the most relevant lines with arrows.

----> This seems to be where the 500 internal server error occurred, when trying to delete capture 7984. In the production.log, it's fairly clear this was a `DELETE` request on the route `/captures/7984`. On the unicorn log, why does this show up as `DELETE /500 HTTP/1.0 500`? To me, this appears to be requesting the delete the path `/500` and returning with a 500 response.

--------> This is where the `SurveySeason` gets deleted. In the unicorn log, it seems very clear that someone from  sent a request to `DELETE` this object explicitly. However, on the production.log all I get is `Completed 302 Found in 193305.5ms (ActiveRecord: 11008.7ms)`. Seems pretty mysterious to me. Any ideas why these events would be reported differently?

I'm hoping to get to the bottom of this.